# MOSFET package with lower thermal resistance than D2PAK

Tags: mosfet, heat, packages

As far as PCB surface mount MOSFET packages go, does D2PAK generally have the lowest thermal (junction to ambient) resistance? Are there other packages with lower \$R_{jc}\$?

This question is based on this document:

[PACKAGE THERMAL RESISTANCE TABLE from Linear](http://www.linear.com/docs/39215)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Junction-to-**ambient** thermal resistance has a lot to do with the PCB design, PCB materials and any heat sinking.

Have a look at, for example, the [IRF7749](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irf7749l2pbf.pdf), which can have junction to ambient of 12.5°C/W with a clip heatsink and lots of copper on the board.

Answer (score 1):

Watch your clearances. The exterior body of the DirectFETs active with the drain usually depending on what rated voltages you need. These FETs are awesome! But you'll have to think twice about designing in an automotive grade DirectFET, as their lead times are astronomical.